# problem in aligning depth and color image on YCB dataset

Tags: alignment

First, for sure, alignment means if a pixel (x0,y0) in RGB image is something's edge, the pixels around (x0,y0) in depth image should change suddenly because the depth is from the object to the background, do I understand this right?
when i try YCB dataset using code from official web page, it looks like something is wrong. As you can see in the image, i think 1.15 should in B area, 0.71 should in A, and 0.79->C, 0.73->D. But actual values of B-A-C-D are 1.11-1.12-1.14-1.15. (the values is depth value, and background color is the RGB image, both are 480*640, and red-masked is invalid depth of 0 value).

[aligned RGB-Depth image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnqmG.jpg)

I tried both code from YCB, and given by chatGPT-4, got nearly same result.

YCB page: http://ycb-benchmarks.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

code from YCB: http://ycb-benchmarks.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/scripts_to_publish/ycb_generate_point_cloud.py

Is that possible that YCB's code is wrong somewhere(for example, intrinsic matrix)? or what i belive about alignment is wrong?